# update sprite position with schedule function

Tags: c++, sprite, cocos2d-x

In my game I have an animated sprite. I added box2d to my game to add gravity. now I want to update my sprite's position using the schedule function. I got it working with objective-C, but I want it to be a multiplatform game so now I'm trying it in c++.

In my init I have the following line:

```
this->schedule(cocos2d::SEL_SCHEDULE(View::tick(1.0f)));
```

and the method tick:

```
void View::tick(float dt) {
world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
if(b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
}
}
}
```

I get the following error on the line in my init: "cannot cast from type ' void' to member pointer type 'coco2d::sel_schedule' (aka void coco2d::CCobject::*)(float)

I have no idea what to do now. I tried to google, but everyone either uses objective - c or schedule_selector (which apparently doesn't work anymore)

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which class you define schedule method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not be using the schedule function to update a single sprite.

In your scene class, override the virtual method for update(...):

```
virtual void update(float dt)
{
    CCLOG("This was called.");
    // Do updates for everything in the scene you need to call on a tick.
}
```

Also, override onEnter() and onExitTransitionDidStart().  In the first, call scheduleUpdate to set up your scene for automatically being called on a tick.  In the second, call unscheduledUpdate (as the scene is exiting) to stop the updates.

```
void IntroScene::onEnter()
{
   CCScene::onEnter();
   scheduleUpdate();
}

void IntroScene::onExitTransitionDidStart()
{
   CCScene::onExitTransitionDidStart();
   unscheduleUpdate();
}
```

Doing it this way gives you explicit control over what gets updated when...you only have a single function called during an update cycle.

**HOWEVER**, if you really want to do it:

Declare your custom updater like this:

```
void IntroScene::myUpdate(float dt)
{
   CCLOG("Also called");
}
```

Schedule it like this:

```
schedule(schedule_selector(IntroScene::myUpdate), 1.0f);
```

Unschedule it like this:

```
unschedule(schedule_selector(IntroScene::myUpdate));
```

** **NOTE** ** As far as I know, you can only "schedule" objects derived from CCNode.

Was this helpful?

Comment: I tried it as you suggested and it works :). I'm not just updating 1 sprite though. I want to update every sprite. Atm only my character is a dynamic body though so only 1 moving sprite.

Comment: Glad I could help.  You might check out this as well: https://github.com/NonlinearIdeas/RotatedFixtureDemo