# Slow down sprite's movement

Tags: c++, sprite, cocos2d-x

In my scene class I've overridden the update function and I call scheduleUpdate() in the onEnter() method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608607/update-sprite-position-with-schedule-function). So in the update function I call the update of my layer class which should update my sprites:

```
void View::update(float dt)
{
    world->Step(dt, 10, 10);
    for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext())
    {
        if(b->GetUserData() != NULL  && b->GetType() != b2_kinematicBody))
        {
            cocos2d::CCSprite *data = (cocos2d::CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
            data->setPosition(ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO));
            data->setRotation(-1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle()));
        }
    }

}
```

At the moment, the only movement is falling down because of gravity. However, the character moves so fast. It almost instantaneously hits the floor. Is there a way to slow this down? 
When I used [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28602/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-bouncing-balls) for objective c, the ball was falling down much slower.

Comment: Are you controlling/limiting how many times update() is being called per second?

Comment: @drescherjm no I am not

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly set the mass of your character? Try to reduce it. Also I recommend you to use a small [wrapper](https://github.com/hannon235/GBox2DX) which makes life with box2d and cocos2d-x much easier.

Comment: The density is 1.0. I'll take a look at the wrapper later. It looks promising.

Comment: Provided update code is OK. Probably you wrongly set up your objects or apply some force to them.

Comment: Found the problem. I set the position of my sprite to the center of my screen, but I set the position of the body to the bottom. So in the first frame the sprite immediately appeared on the bottom side.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I set the position of my sprite to the center of my screen, but I set the position of the body to the bottom. So in the first frame the sprite immediately appeared on the bottom side.

So if anyone has the same problem: check the position of your body. Not just the sprite's position.